# How to add font awesome to link_to method on rails using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, font-awesome

I am trying to modify my layout just to add link_to to my drop down list.

previous code:

```
  %li.divider
  %li
    %a{:href => "#"}
      %i.fa.fa-user-profile
      Add new user
```

i edited like this:

```
 %li.divider
 %li
   = link_to '<i class="fa fa-user-profile"></i> Add new user'.html_safe, new_user_path
```

And everything looks fine, but fa-user-profile is 0px x 0px and it is invisible. What i done wrong?

Html output:

[image]

Comment: in the former code you are doing `fa-user-plus` and the later `fa-user-profile` ?

Comment: it doesnt matter, both classes exists, i just forgot to modify. I'll edit my post. Actually it is something wrong with rendering, coz it's 0px x 0px, I think i did very stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: can you share the resulting html?

Comment: @Minato edited post, check it

Comment: please post the previous html as well

Comment: @Minato it is the same both ways, just with link_to its 0px x 0px

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`link_to` has a "blocky" form](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) that accepts custom inner markup:

```
= link_to new_user_path do
  %i.fa.fa-user-profile
  Add new user
```

Regarding element invisibility: the element itself should be filled in by FontAwesome's CSS, using `font-family` (on class `fa`) and `content` (on specific icon class). If you don't have them, it means you don't have the necessary CSS.

How to add it, depends on the way FontAwesome is integrated into your asset pipeline. [`font-awesome-sass`' README](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) has pretty clear instructions on that, your solution's might differ.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't help, still the same problem

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [raw()](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)

```
= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-user-profile"></i> Add new user'), new_user_path
```